# Quarkus with new relic integration (javaagent)

Tags: newrelic, quarkus, javaagents

I have an application that need send web transactions and database transactions to New Relic through Java-Agent.

**Resource example:**

```
@Path("/example")
class ExampleResource{
    @GET
    fun hello() = "hello"
}
```

**Compile command:**
`gradle clean quarkusBuild --uber-jar`

**Run command:**

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx512m \
-javaagent:/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.config.file=/newrelic/newrelic.yml \
-jar "example.jar"
```

But the New Relic did not receive the data. Does anyone have any ideas for this to work?

Comment: Are you doing a test with native mode? Have you tried a test with JVM mode?

Comment: I am using the JVM mode

Answer (score 0):

It was added the @Trace annotation to force the instrumentation and it worked successful.

**Annotation**

`import com.newrelic.api.agent.Trace`

**Dependency**

`implementation("com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:<version>")`